# is it safe to include files based on query string values in php?

Tags: php, security

I'm trying to include some files dynamically and I need to get some parameters from query string. this is the part of script that does the trick for me:

```
require_once ROOT . "/components/{$_GET['c']}/" . str_replace('_', '/', $classname) . '.php';
```

Is it safe to include files like this?

Comment: You should **always** validate any user-initiated data, and never use as provided. You could, for example, first check if this value fits the right alphanumeric pattern and then check if that directory even exists by getting a list of the directories in `components` and check if that value is in that list.

Comment: thanks for the answer jared. can you please explain how can this code be unsafe? (other than changing the directory by using values like '../' in the c parameter)

Comment: I don't write exploits and frankly, I can't tell you how to exploit it either. Reread the comment and you'll see I suggested a best practice. Simply, do not trust any data from outside your system, including resource requests.

Answer (score 4):

No! This is never safe to do. Always sanitize input coming from the outside world. You could use an array to do this:

```
$allowed = array(
  'page1',
  'page2'
);
```

Now check if `$_GET['c']` is inside the array and include your file then.

```
if(in_array($_GET['c'], $allowed)) {
  $dir = $_GET['c'];
  require_once ROOT . "/components/{$dir}". str_replace('_', '/', $classname);
}
```

Comment: this approach seems to be best but i don't think its applicable for me because if i could list out the valid directories, i would include the scripts manually. I guess i should try regexp validation for directory names

Answer (score 2):

No, never. *Everything* from outside must get treatened as "malicious" first. This means, you must validate everything before use

For example

```
$c = $_GET['c'];
if (in_array($c, $listOfValidFolders) {
  require_once ROOT . "/components/$c/" . str_replace('_', '/', $classname);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

no, because if you have any file that is in that directory. You should have a list of accepted values and check if the requested page is within that.

Answer (score 1):

No. Check it first. Even better, have a whitelist of files that can be included. Anything else, send a `404 Not Found` response.